# Allow alternate input formats in Angular UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

Angular UI datepicker altInputFormats does not allow formats that I need. I want to avoid using jQuery.

I need users to be able to input things like:

10JUN16

10JUN2016

AUGUST12

06/12 = June 12th, current year

06-10

061016

But the uibDateParser does not have compatible format codes. 
I found a similar issue [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/6053) but the advice was to change the source code which I'd prefer not to mess with. I'm thinking that some kind of parser in my Angular controller might help?

Any ideas? Here is a plunker I've been playing with

where I have

`$scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'dd-MMM-yy', 'dd-MMM-yyyy', 'd!-M!-yy'];`

But the others won't work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/yNERf1jrtThVvJ1SBjBY?p=preview